# Fall down or fall out

Tags: phrase-request, phrasal-verbs, prepositional-phrases, collocations

Is it correct to say **"He fell down from the tree"** or we have to use **fell out** ?. Maybe these two forms are possible? Please explain me :)) thank You.

Comment: That would be *fell out **of** the tree*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**He fell **out of the tree, wagon, cart, car** (the door is open)**.

**Fall out implies you are "in something"** and you fall out of it. For trees, we typically say to climb a tree, and to be "up in the tree". It is viewed as a "container". Therefore, you fall out of it. It is NOT a two-word verb.

Please note: You can also "fall out" with a group of friends. No longer be friends with them. It is a two-word verb here.

There is also *fall **off of something***: He fell **off the roof**, he fell **off the branch** [of a tree where he was sitting], he fell off the pedestal, he fell off the boat. Here, it's OFF, because you are considered to be "**on a surface**". This is not a two-word verb.

/Fall down/ (a two-word verb) means to fall to the ground or to a surface without the idea of being inside something. **He was walking down the street and fell down**. **The old lady tripped and fell down on the walkway***

However, we would say: **He fell down the stairs**. In that sense, it's **fall** and **down the stairs** and is not a two-word verb.